# How to display hierarchy member where measure is null (mdx)

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I want to display hierarchy in SSRS which include the members with null measure. 
The problem in mdx query is that when I remove NON EMPTY clouse I got 'System.OutOfMemoryException' due to the 
large crossjoin between time, products and hierarchy dimension. Any idea how to soleve it? The query is as follow:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY  { (
[Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
   )} ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY { (
[Organization Structure].[Description].[Description].Allmembers
* [Organization Structure].[ID].[ID]
* [Organization Structure].[ParentID].[ParentID]
*[Products].[Name].[Name]
*[Time].[Hierarchy].[MothsAndDays]
)} 
DIMENSION
 PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, 
 LEVEL_NUMBER ON ROWS 
 FROM [MyCube]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the memory problems that you have appear on the Reporting Services server, not the Analysis Services server, you can use the `HAVING` clause at the end of the `ROWS` select part instead of `NON EMPTY` at the start of it to restrict the rows:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY  { (
[Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
   )} ON COLUMNS,

[Organization Structure].[Description].[Description].Allmembers
* [Organization Structure].[ID].[ID]
* [Organization Structure].[ParentID].[ParentID]
*[Products].[Name].[Name]
*[Time].[Hierarchy].[MothsAndDays]

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, LEVEL_NUMBER 

HAVING <whatever the condition is to display a row>

ON ROWS 
 FROM [MyCube]
```

As you did not state exactly how you want to determine the rows that you want to display, I left that as `<whatever the condition is to display a row>` above. The way this works is that Analysis Services first builds up the result set for the complete cross product of all row hierarchies, and then evaluates the condition to remove rows from this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the NonEmpty (without gap) function instead on the hierarchies you are ok to get rid of nulls? So for example:

```
SELECT 
//NON EMPTY  
{ (
[Measures].[SOME MEASURE]
   )} ON COLUMNS,
//NON EMPTY 
{ (
[Organization Structure].[Description].[Description].Allmembers
* NONEMPTY([Organization Structure].[ID].[ID],[Measures].[SOME MEASURE])
* [Organization Structure].[ParentID].[ParentID]
* NONEMPTY([Products].[Name].[Name],[Measures].[SOME MEASURE])
* [Time].[Hierarchy].[MothsAndDays]
)} 
DIMENSION
 PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, 
 LEVEL_NUMBER ON ROWS 
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. I need to handle the situation Department -> is null, its Unit ->has value. When it happens the Department won't occure in raport. On the other hand if I remove NOT EMPTY clouse the query result explode.

Comment: @arth81 Well, you have to decide if you want to show members with null measure, and accept to get millions of results, or if you want few rows, but not those members where the measure is null. You cannot have both!

Comment: Generally speaking I need some of recodrds with nulls to display it on the report. Imagine organization where Department doesnt't have values in measure group (nulls) eg. MArketing Dep., and one that does eg. Sells Dep. Now subdepartment of MArketing Department has some values. So I need to display: MArkteting Dep ->null, subdepartment of Marketing Dep. ->300, Sells Dep.->10000. But of course the structure is bigger and I don;t need eg. Cleaning Team on report. If I remove 'not empty' I include all units but in the result: I dont'need all (eg. Clean Team), the query explode with an exception.